# 2D interpolation in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, interpolation

So this program is supposed to ask the user for a temperature in *Kelvin*s and the starting *Ne*. And then interpolate to find the given value.

The `temp` array is all temperatures and is used to find what temperature we are between.

The `n` array is all the *Ne*'s and is used to find what Ne we are between.

Whatever spots we get in each will end up being the spot we are interpolating in the bigger array, HPE.

The main function ask the user for a temperature and *Ne* and calls upon the Interpolation function.

The interpol function is the function that interpolates. First it finds where the given temperature is in the temp array. Then it finds where the given Ne is in the n array. Then it uses that spot (HPE[k][l]) to do the 2D interpolation.

My problem is when I run it and enter values that should be giving me an answer, I get "The value determined is `nan`"

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double interpol(double Ti, double Ne);

int main()
{
    int ni;
    double Ti, result, Ne;

    printf("\nEnter the temperature in kelvins and Ne separated by a space.\n");
    ni = scanf("%lf %lf", &Ti, &Ne);
    result = interpol(Ti, Ne);
    printf("\nThe value determined is %lf\n", result);
}


double interpol(double Ti, double Ne)
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    double y1, y2, y3, y4, t, u, p;
    double temp[15] = {
        1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0,
        6000.0, 7000.0, 8000.0, 9000.0, 10000.0,
        11000.0, 12000.0, 13000.0, 14000.0, 15000.0};
    double n[8] = {10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0};
    double HPE[15][8] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0017, 0.0002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.2980, 0.0407, 0.0042, 0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.9582, 0.6961, 0.1864, 0.0224, 0.0023, 0.0002, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.9979, 0.9791, 0.8241, 0.3191, 0.0448, 0.0047, 0.0005, 0.0},
        {0.9998, 0.9980, 0.9804, 0.8335, 0.3335, 0.0477, 0.0050, 0.0005},
        {1.0, 0.9997, 0.9971, 0.9713, 0.7719, 0.2529, 0.0327, 0.0034},
        {1.0, 0.9999, 0.9994, 0.9939, 0.9425, 0.6211, 0.1408, 0.0161},
        {1.0, 1.0, 0.9998, 0.9984, 0.9841, 0.8606, 0.3817, 0.0581},
        {1.0, 1.0, 0.9999, 0.9995, 0.9948, 0.9503, 0.6568, 0.1607},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9998, 0.9980, 0.9807, 0.8358, 0.3373},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9999, 0.9992, 0.9917, 0.9229, 0.5448}
    };

    for (i = 1 ; i < 16 ; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] <= Ti && temp[i+1] >= Ti)
        {
            k = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (j = 1 ; j < 9 ; j++)
    {
        if (n[j] <= Ne && n[j+1] >= Ne)
        {
            l = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    y1 = HPE[k][l];
    y2 = HPE[k+1][l];
    y3 = HPE[k+1][l+1];
    y4 = HPE[k][l+1];

    t = (Ti - (HPE[k][0])) / ((HPE[k+1][0]) - (HPE[k][0]));
    u = (Ne - (HPE[0][l])) / ((HPE[0][l+1]) - (HPE[0][l]));
    p = ((1 - t) * (1 - u) * y1) + (t * (1 - u) * y2) + (t * u * y3) + ((1 - t) * u * y4);

    return (p);
}
```

Comment: You capture the return value from `scanf()` you don't use it though, why? And please don't use parentheses for `return` it's ugly and makes `return` look like a funcion.

Comment: Where are you protecting against a divide by `0` (or where your divisor is close to `0`)?

Comment: the variable `ni` is being set, but never used.   A strong indication of a logic error.

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code, (like 16, 9, 15, 8) to avoid problems that such magic numbers create in the understanding of the code and to avoid future maintenance headaches, strongly suggest using enum or #define to give those magic numbers meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: this statement (similar to some other statements in the code:) `for (i = 1 ; i < 16 ; i++)` Because array offsets in C start with 0, does not correctly address the offsets in the `temp` array.  a much better statement would be: `for (i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++)` or even better: `for (i = 0 ; i < (sizeof( temp)/sizeof(temp[0]) ; i++)`

Comment: when defining/declaring arrays with initialization values, do not bother with writing the counts into the declaration, just let the data define the sizes. I.E. double HPE[][] = { and double n[] and double temp[] = { Also, those arrays seem to never be changed, so would be better defined using the 'const' modifier and perhaps moved outside the function by using the 'static' modifier so they are not consuming the stack space

Answer (score 4):

You have an obvious mistake to any [c](/questions/tagged/c) programmer, arrays of size `N` in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are indexed from `0` to `N - 1`. There are some languages where an array of size `N` will be indexed from `1` to `N` like [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal) for example, but in [c](/questions/tagged/c) it's from `0` to `N - 1`.

Comment: Correct! That's absolutely critical to programming in C.